# Getting segmentation fault while from a file using fscanf in c

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, file-handling

```
int main() {
    FILE *matrix_r;
    matrix_r=fopen("matrix.txt","r");
    double x;char c;
    while(feof(matrix_r)){
        fscanf(matrix_r,"%lf%c",&x,&c);
        printf("%lf%c",x,c);
    }
    fclose(matrix_r);

    return 0;
}
```

Trying to read float values from the file but getting segmentation fault core dumped error. matrix.txt stores a matrix of floats.

contents of matrix.txt are below.

```
0.000000,876.671546,448.879717,1349.827396
876.671546,0.000000,1319.195209,964.193445
448.879717,1319.195209,0.000000,1741.628261
1349.827396,964.193445,1741.628261,0.000000
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You do not check whether you got a valid `FILE*`. If you run your program from wrong directoy you may not find the file and then try to use a `NULL` pointer with `feof` and `fscanf`. You should also always check the return value of `fscanf` and other IO functions.

Comment: Did you run your program in a debugger? It should tell you where you get the segmentation fault and then you can inspect what values are stored in the involved variables.

Comment: `while(feof(matrix_r))` would usually be `while(!feof(matrix_r))` but even that is wrong. Use the value returned by `fscanf` to control the loop. `while(fscanf(matrix_r, %lf%c", &x, &c) == 2)`

Comment: If the intention was `while(!feof(matrix_r))`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feoffile-always-wrong.

Comment: Note that [`while (!feof(file))` is always wrong!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/15168)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fopen()` failed and `feof(NULL)` caused the segfault. If `fopen()` was successful then `feof()` would return false and the loop wouldn't run but your program wouldn't segfault.

Check the return value of `fopen()` & `fscanf()`.  You only need to call `feof()` if you need to find out why `fscanf()` failed to read 2 items.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    FILE *matrix_r = fopen("matrix.txt", "r");
    if(!matrix_r) {
        perror("fopen");
        return 1;
    }
    for(;;) {
        double x;
        char c;
        int rv = fscanf(matrix_r, "%lf%c", &x, &c);
        if(rv != 2)
            break;
        printf("%lf%c", x, c);
    }
    fclose(matrix_r);
}
```

Here is the output:

```
0.000000,876.671546,448.879717,1349.827396
876.671546,0.000000,1319.195209,964.193445
448.879717,1319.195209,0.000000,1741.628261
1349.827396,964.193445,1741.628261,0.000000
```

Comment: It will not work as it will fail at the end of the first line.

Comment: @0___________ Why do you think that?  It works for me.

Comment: *It works for me.*  Did it?  Was the final `0.00000`  printed?

Comment: @AndrewHenle Yes.  I updated answer with output (which is identical to input). What's the concern?

Answer (score 1):

1. You do not check if `fopen` was successful. Calls to `feof` or `fscanf` if the file pointer is NULL invoke Undefined Behaviour
2. `while(feof(matrix_r)){`

`while(!feof(...)))` is always wrong ([Why is “while( !feof(file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feoffile-always-wrong)), but your one has no logical sense at all (as you want to `scanf` if it is the end of the file).